# A way to extract hands from a video

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I wonder whether it would be possible to extract only hands from a video with matlab. In the video hands perform some gesture. Because first frames are only background I tried in this way:

```
readerObj = VideoReader('VideoWithHands.mp4');
nFrames = readerObj.NumberOfFrames;
fr = get(readerObj, 'FrameRate');
writerObj = VideoWriter('Hands.mp4', 'MPEG-4');
set(writerObj, 'FrameRate', fr);
open(writerObj);
bg = read(readerObj, 1);   %background
for k = 1 : nFrames
      frame = read(readerObj, k);
      hands = imabsdiff(frame,bg);
      writeVideo(writerObj,hands);
end
close(writerObj);
```

But I realized that colors of the hands are not "real" and they are transparent. Is there a better way to extract them from video keeping colors and opacity level exploiting the first frames (background)?

**EDIT:** Well, I have found a good setting for vision.ForegroundDetector object, now hands are white logical regions but when I try to visualize them with:

```
videoSource = vision.VideoFileReader('VideoWithHands.mp4', 'VideoOutputDataType', 'uint8');

detector = vision.ForegroundDetector('NumTrainingFrames', 46, 'InitialVariance', 4000, 'MinimumBackgroundRatio', 0.2);

videoplayer = vision.VideoPlayer();
hands = uint8(zeros(720,1280,3));
while ~isDone(videoSource)

    frame = step(videoSource);
    fgMask = step(detector, frame);

    [m,n] = find(fgMask);
    a = [m n];
    if isempty(a)==true

        hands(:,:,:) = uint8(zeros(720,1280,3));
    else


        hands(m,n,1) = frame(m,n,1);
        hands(m,n,2) = frame(m,n,2);
        hands(m,n,3) = frame(m,n,3);

    end



    step(videoplayer, hands)



end

release(videoplayer)
release(videoSource)
```

or put them into a videofile with:

```
eaderObj = VideoReader('Video 9.mp4');
nFrames = readerObj.NumberOfFrames;
fr = get(readerObj, 'FrameRate');



writerObj = VideoWriter('hands.mp4', 'MPEG-4');

set(writerObj, 'FrameRate', fr);

detector = vision.ForegroundDetector('NumTrainingFrames', 46, 'InitialVariance', 4000, 'MinimumBackgroundRatio', 0.2);
open(writerObj);

bg = read(readerObj, 1);


frame = uint8(zeros(size(bg)));

for k = 1 : nFrames


frame = read(readerObj, k);

   fgMask =  step(detector, frame);


[m,n] = find(fgMask);

hands = uint8(zeros(720,1280));

if isempty([m n]) == true

    hands(:,:) = uint8(zeros(720,1280));

else

    hands(m,n) = frame(m,n);

end

 writeVideo(writerObj,mani);





end

close(writerObj);
```

...my PC crashes. Some suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're trying to cancel out the background, making it black, right?
The easiest way to do this should be to filter it, you can do that by comparing your difference data to a threshold value and then using the result as indices to set a custom background.

```
filtered = imabsdiff(frame,bg);
bgindex = find( filtered < 10 );
frame(bgindex) = custombackground(bgindex);
```

where custombackground is whatever image file you want to put into the background. If you want it to be just black or white, use 0 or 255 instead of `custombackground(bgindex)`. Note that the numbers depend on your video data's format and could be inaccurate (except 0, this one should always be right). If too much gets filtered out, lower the `10` above, if too much remains unfiltered, increase the `10`.

At the end, you write your altered frame back into the video, so it just replaces the `hands` variable in your code.

Also, depending on your format, you might have to do the comparison across RGB values. This is slightly more complicated as it involves checking 3 values at the same time and doing some magic with the indices. This is the RGB version (works with anything containing 3 color bands):

```
filtered = imabsdiff(frame,bg); % differences at each pixel in each color band
totalfiltered = sum(filtered,3); % sums up the differences
                                 % in each color band (RGB)
bgindex = find( totalfiltered < 10 ); % extracts indices of pixels
                                      % with color close to bg
allind = sub2ind( [numel(totalfiltered),3] , repmat(bgindex,1,3) , ...
                  repmat(1:3,numel(bgindex),1) ); % index magic

frame(allind) = custombackground(allind); % copy custom background into frame
```

**EDIT :**

Here's a detailed explanation of the index magic.

Let's assume a 50x50 image. Say the pixel at row 2, column 5 is found to be background, then `bgindex` will contain the number 202 (linear index corresponding to `[2,5] = (5-1)*50+2` ). What we need is a set of 3 indices corresponding to the matrix coordinates `[2,5,1]`, `[2,5,2]` and `[2,5,3]`. That way, we can change all 3 color bands corresponding to that pixel. To make calculations easier, this approach actually assumes linear indexing for the image and thus converts it to a 2500x1 image. Then it expands the 3 color bands, creating a 2500x3 matrix. We now construct the indices `[202,1]`, `[202,2]` and `[202,3]` instead.

To do that, we first construct a matrix of indices by repeating our values. `repmat` does this for us, it creates the matrices `[202 202 202]` and `[1 2 3]`. If there were more pixels in `bgindex`, the first matrix would contain more rows, each repeating the linear pixel coordinates 3 times. The second matrix would contain additional `[1 2 3]` rows. The first argument to `sub2ind` is the size of the matrix, in this case, 2500x3, so we calculate the number of pixels with `numel` applied to the sum vector (which collapses the image's 3 bands into 1 value and thus has 1 value per pixel) and add a static 3 in the second dimension.

`sub2ind` now takes each element from the first matrix as a row index, each corresponding element from the second matrix as a column index and converts them to linear indices into a matrix of the size we determined earlier. In our example, this results in the indices `[202 2702 5202]`. `sub2ind` preserves the shape of the inputs, so if we had 10 background pixels, this result would have the size 10x3. But since linear indexing doesn't care about the shape of the index matrix, it just takes all of those values.

To confirm this is correct, let's revert the values in the example. The original image data would have the size 50x50x3. For an NxMxP matrix, a linear index to the subscript `[n m p]` can be calculated as `ind = (p-1)*M*N + (m-1)*N + n`. Using our values, we get the following:

```
[2 5 1] => 202
[2 5 2] => 2702
[2 5 3] => 5202
```

`ind2sub` confirms this.

Comment: In resulting video I still see something of the background; as custom background I setted a zeros(size(frame))

Comment: I haven't tested this, but just a plain 0 should also work. Saves memory.

If there are still relics, it's probably fluctuations in the background color. Increasing the filter threshold (10 in my example above) should help with that problem, but be aware this also increases the probability of foreground pixels getting filtered. If the colors are very different, however, it should be safe to go as far as 50.

Theoretically, you could filter each band seperately, but this is a lot more complicated. Same goes for filtering an entire connected area. It's possible, but not as simple as this trick.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try with some threshold values. One question: can you explain what does it perform with....   allind = sub2ind( [numel(totalfiltered),3] , repmat(bgindex,1,3) , ...
repmat(1:3,numel(bgindex),1) );    ????

Comment: That converts the indices. I'll edit a detailed explanation above, the comments don't allow enough characters.

Comment: Also, it basically just does `sub2ind( size(filtered) , ind2sub( size(totalfiltered),bgindex) , i )`, in a `for i=1:3` loop, but uses the vectorized form to save resources.

Comment: Sorry if I re-open the question, but what would happen if object had the same color as the background ? I tried with a white object in a white background and when hands are close to object output video shows the background.

Comment: The same that happens if someone goes into a bluebox and has clothes with the same color as the background. The object is mistaken for background by the algorithm. There's no way around that except making sure the background has a unique color. Or feature extraction, which is one hell of a lot more complicated...

Comment: So, it would be easy if background is white and object is black or vice versa, is it?

Comment: Yes. The background should be far away from the objects in terms of color. The method i proposed calculates the difference in the red, green and Blue color bands and flags a point as "background" if this difference totals to less than some threshold value (10 in the example above). If the color is too similar to the background, the algorithm won't notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way.  The computer vision system toolbox includes a `vision.ForegroundDetector` object that does what you need. It implements the Gaussian Mixture Model algorithm for background subtraction.

Comment: I used it, but it do a good detection if foreground are moving constantly.

Comment: @user3063488 If Matlab is crashing your PC, you should call Mathworks tech support.